# Crear una librería dinamica .so de un archivo C con las librerías incluidas

Tags: c

Tengo un archivo .c que quiero pasar a librería dinámica .so para esta poderla utilizar en python. Para esto ya hice algunas pruebas creando esta librería, pero al utilizarla en python me marca un problema sobre que no están incluidas unas librerías:

```
pi@pi:~ $ python3 prueba.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/prueba.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pruebalib
  File "/home/pi/pruebalib.py", line 4, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libmifare_e.so')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libmifare_e.so: undefined symbol: nfc_open
```

Este es mi archivo .c :

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <nfc/nfc.h>
#include <freefare.h>

char *csn(){
    
    int error = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    nfc_device *device = NULL;
    FreefareTag *tags = NULL;

    nfc_connstring devices[8];
    size_t device_count;
    char *tag_uid;

    nfc_context *context;
    nfc_init(&context);
    if (context == NULL)
    errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Unable to init libnfc (malloc)");

    device_count = nfc_list_devices(context, devices, 8);
    if (device_count <= 0)
    errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "No NFC device found.");

    for (size_t d = 0; d < device_count; d++) {
        device = nfc_open(context, devices[d]);
        if (!device) {
            warnx("nfc_open() failed.");
            error = EXIT_FAILURE;
            continue;
        }
   
        tags = freefare_get_tags(device);
        if (!tags) {
            nfc_close(device);
            errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error listing tags.");
        }

        for (int i = 0; (!error) && tags[i]; i++) {

            tag_uid = freefare_get_tag_uid(tags[i]);
            
        }
    return tag_uid;
    free(tag_uid);
    freefare_free_tags(tags);
    nfc_close(device);
    }
    nfc_exit(context);
    exit(error);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
}
```

Y así es como intenté hacer el archivo .so:

```
gcc -shared -W -o libmifare_e.so mifare-desfire-ernesto.o
```

(El archivo .o es generado de manera automática al ejecutar un `make` de la librería propia que estoy utilizando)

¿Hay algún paso que me estoy saltando sobre cómo añadir las librerías del archivo .c?

Comment: En [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) puedes encontrar información sobre eso. No tengo idea de como se hace, pero si que hay algunos tutoriales como este https://youtu.be/a65JdvOaygM

Comment: Las librerías .so **no tienen main**. Esto es así porque no son programas ejecutables sino partes de un programa más grande

Comment: ¿Sabes como se hace la libreria .so?